# toprule set up for two sub tables

Tags: tables

First thing first, my LaTeX code,

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    
\usepackage[letterpaper, top=0.25in, bottom=0.25in, left=0.25in, right=0.25in]{geometry}    
\usepackage{multirow,array,varwidth,spreadtab,caption}    
\usepackage{booktabs}    
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs,caption}    
\usepackage{multirow,array,varwidth,spreadtab,}    
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs,caption}    
\usepackage{ragged2e}    
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}    
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\RaggedLeft\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}    
%%% change contents font %%%    
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}    
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}     
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
%%% %%% %%% %%% %%% %%% %%%%    
\usepackage[active,floats,tightpage]{preview}% just for showing only table    
    \setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}    

\begin{document}    
\begin{table}    
\newcommand{\fl}[1]{\makebox[.12\textwidth]{#1}}    
\centering    
\begin{tabular}{    
  l    
  *{8}{S[table-format=1.1,table-alignment=right]}    
 }    
& \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{DETINDISND -M\$}}    
\multicolumn{3}{r}{\textbf{FUTURE MET OUTCOME BEFORE LANCOME TEXAS-M\$}}\\    
\cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{2-6}\cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{7-9}    
&{\fl{OPERA}}&{\fl{Findfall\,Profit}}&{\fl{Development}} & {\fl{TranSportation}}            & {} & {}& {} & {\fl{DISCOUNTED}}&\\    
{\fl{\textbf{PERY}}&{\fl{COSTCO}}    &{\fl{TEXAS}}           &{\fl{BLABLA}} &     {\fl{and\,Others}} & {\fl{Total}} & {\fl{AnnE}} & {\fl{CuCuMBive}} &     {\fl{$@10.00\%$}}\\    
\cmidrule(lr){1-1} \cmidrule(lr){2-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-6} \cmidrule(lr){7-7} \cmidrule(lr){8-8} \cmidrule(lr){9-9}
\textbf{2012} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\    
\textbf{2013} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\    
\textbf{2014} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\    
\midrule    
\textbf{Sub-Total}     & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\    
\textbf{Remainder}     & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\    
\textbf{Total\,Future} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\    

\end{tabular}    
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

and what I get, shown in pic below,
[image: Currently what I got....]

I want to make these three points happen, and I struggle for hours to find a perfect method to deal with but failed.

1. Make separate toprule for two individual sub-tables, one for column
   2-6; the other for column 7-9. Empty space between two top rules,
   if the space equal the `\cmidrule` interval space that would he great.
2. Centering the 2nd caption `{FUTURE MET OUTCOME BEFORE LANCOME
       TEXAS-M\$}` with respect to column 7-9. (Currently, is not...)
3. If possible, is there anyway could minimize the vertical distance
           between rows 2 and 3?

   My ideal outcome would be like pic below, for you as reference. 
   [image: What I am trying to reach...]

Appreciated your kind help. New to LaTeX, would learn anything that help.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest simplifying and adjusting the setup of your table along the following lines:

- use a `tabularx` environment, with its width set to `\textwidth`;
- keep the `S` column type for columns 2 thru 9, while using a centered version of the `X` column type for the 8 subheader cells (to ensure (i) that the full table spans the width of the text block and (ii) that the eight data columns are all equally wide);
- use a modified form of the `X` column type for the right-hand main header material (to allow automatic line breaking); and
- use two plain `\cmidrule` directives to separate the main header cells from the sub-headers.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%% I've commented out the instructions that aren't needed for the example 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[letterpaper, margin=0.25in]{geometry}
%\usepackage{multirow,array,varwidth,spreadtab,caption}
%\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs,caption}
\usepackage{tabularx}
%\usepackage{multirow,array,varwidth,spreadtab,}
%\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs,caption}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
%\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
%\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\RaggedLeft\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X}

%%% change contents font %%%
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%\usepackage[active,floats,tightpage]{preview}% just for showing only table
%    \setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\sisetup{table-format=1.2}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}  % default value: 6pt
\newcommand{\fl}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C}{#1}}
%\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l *{8}{S} @{}}
\toprule
\textbf{PERY} 
& \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{DETINDISND (M\$)}}
& \multicolumn{3}{>{\hsize=3\hsize}C@{}}{\textbf{FUTURE MET OUTCOME \mbox{BEFORE} LANCOME TEXAS (M\$)}}\\
\cmidrule(lr){2-6} \cmidrule(l){7-9} %% separators between headers and sub-headers
& \fl{OPERA COSTCO} & \fl{Findfall Profit TEXAS} & \fl{Development BLABLA} & \fl{Transportation and Others}  & \fl{Total} & \fl{AnnE} & \fl{CuCuMBive} & \fl{DISCOUNTED @10\%}\\
\midrule
\textbf{2012} & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00\\
\textbf{2013} & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00\\
\textbf{2014} & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00\\
\midrule
\textbf{Subtotal}      & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00\\
\textbf{Remainder}     & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00\\
\textbf{Total Future}  & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```